# What tools should I use if a want to deploy a NodeJS application in my own server?

Tags: node.js, server, centos

I would like to have a control panel where I can manage all my node servers/applications and auto start them on system start. I also need to make this apps public to the web with an SSL certificate.

I've been reading about a PaaS called CapRover and CentOS Control Web Panel but I am not sure if those are the tools I need.

Thank you!

Comment: I've made this using a windows server and deploying it in IIS but i cant get the logs in real time and it is hard to make CI/CD.